# How to wrap function call inside of Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

After exporting the required modules and setting up the variables

```
let AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const AmazonCognitoIdentity = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');

const USER_POOL_ID = 'us-east-1_vkXRQuP4U';
const CLIENT_ID = 'mipa4trls0l7323om33mlk80e8';

const poolData = { 
  UserPoolId : USER_POOL_ID, ClientId : CLIENT_ID
};
const POOL = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);

let email = "my.email@domain.com";
let password = "My.Password!";
```

I can go ahead and call `signUp` command:

```
POOL.signUp(email, password, [], null, function(err, result) {
  console.log('...result:', result);
});
```

And it works well. Next I want to wrap the `POOL.signUp(email, password...)` inside `async` function `sign_up` like so:

```
async function sign_up(email, password) {
  POOL.signUp(email, password, [], null, function(err, result) {
    console.log('...sign_up.result:', result);
    return result;
  })
};

async function main() {
  let signupData = await sign_up(email, password);
  console.log('...main.signupData:', signupData);
  return signupData;
};

main().then((error, data) => {console.log('...error, data:', error, data)});
```

While it works fine, the order of the calls that get executed is wrong as the `main` function doesn't wait for the `sign_up()` function to complete. In attempt to correct this behavior I wrap the `POOL.signUp(email, password...)` inside of Promise:

```
async function sign_up(email, password) {

  return await new Promise((resolve) => {
    POOL.signUp(email, password, [], null, {
      onSuccess: (result) => {
        console.log('...result:', result)
        return resolve(result);
      },      
      onFailure: (err) => {
        return resolve(err.message);
      },
    });
  })
};
```

But I am getting the error message:

```
 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: callback is not a function
```

Is there a way to avoid this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- don't need to `await` the Promise you are returning (since we precisely want our function to be async, we want to defer the waiting to the caller)
- `Promise` constructor function needs to provide the second `reject` parameter to be able to access the callback in the function implementation
- pass a callback function as your `POOL.signUp` fourth argument, instead of an object

```
function sign_up(email, password) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    POOL.signUp(email, password, [], null, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err.message);
      }

      console.log('...result:', result)
      resolve(result);
    });
  })
};
```

Comment: I've removed the `async` - a function that returns a promise directly does not need it. Also returning after `reject()`  is a good idea.

Comment: Appreciate the edit. I forgot the return in the control flow, I moved it so that it simply returns the reject call result (for stylistic reasons).

Comment: Well in that case, `if (err) return reject(err.message);` is even more slick. :)

Comment: That's also how i would write it, but it seems somewhat too opinionated for SO ;)

Comment: Arguably the most elegant solution for node.js is `const { promisify } = require('util');` and `POOL.signUpAsync = promisify(POOL.signUp);`. No need to promisify functions manually.

Comment: Agreed. If you have time I think this would be a good standalone answer.

Comment: When the OP is really interested, they'll pick it up from the comments.